# Wordpress CPT blank category page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm aware that similar questions have been asked before, but can't seem to find the appropriate solution.

For a client I developed a custom post type as a module. Although the CPT archive loads fine, the categories display a blank page instead (no errors reported through logs).

The CPT does include

```
$args = array(
  'taxonomies' => array('category'),
  'has_archive' => true,
);
```

The custom post type is courses. Yet, taxonomy-courses.php and category-courses.php do not work. To get the archive to work (did not work standard) the following function is used;

```
function courses_archive_custom($archive_template) {
  global $post;
  if (is_archive() && get_post_type($post) == 'courses' || is_category() && get_post_type($post) == 'courses') {
    $archive_template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'archive-courses.php';
  }
  return $archive_template;
}
```

add_filter('archive_template', 'courses_archive_custom');

Why do templates not work straight away anyway?

Comment: well.. If courses is a CPT, then it is not a tax nor a cat. so what would you expect from that? for the archive to work, You probably just needed to flush your permalinks btw.

Comment: Flushing the permalinks does not fix the issue. I also don't get your tax or cat comment. A CPT can have a custom category template right?

Comment: A custom post type, will use a file like `archive-{post_type}.php` - which you can read more about here : https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: Yes, I'm aware and read the documentation thorougly, yet doesn't work..

Comment: It appears categories in custom post types are taxonomies? Yet, category-courses.php does not work